# XSLT escaping &gt;

Tags: xslt, escaping, xslt-1.0

i have a problem like a lot of people with escaping the > sign.
the data xml file looks like

```
<XML>
<check><![CDATA[value > 60]]></check>
</Xml>
```

with xslt i would like to create a c# function. the checks are items that gone be used in a if statement.

```
public void product(int value)
{
if( <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="actie" />)

this should be: if( value > 60 ) but returns if( value &gt; 60 ) 

}
```

`<xsl:value-of cdata-section-elements="check"/>` can't be used becouse i can't use this data in a template.

disable-output-escaping just returns `&gt;`

hope one of u have a working solution.

thanking you in
advance

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very easy solution. :)

Comment: You wrote *I have a problem like a lot of people with escaping the > sign*. That's not a question, but a statement. Any XML consumer knows how to deal with character entities. Some people have problems when they try to use XML documents with no XML complain consumers.

Comment: Also, it's not clear the serialization method you need to use. There is no escape performed with `text` serialization method as point out by @Dimitre's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks vor the help but it wasn't the solution, had some help from a friend who told me i was doing it wrong on calling the xslt file
What i dit was:

```
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument("../../file.xml");
XslTransform myXslTrans = new XslTransform();
myXslTrans.Load("../../file.xslt");
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("../../file.txt", null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
```

i changed it to:

```
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load("../../file.xslt");
myXslTrans.Transform("../../file.xml", "../../file.cs");
```

now it worked

Comment: Using `XslCompiledTransform` class istead of old `XslTransform` class have nothing to do with your not so well defined question

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need DOE at all. Just specify**:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

**and the result will be unescaped**.

**Here is a small example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
   public void product(int value)
       {
        if( <xsl:value-of select="check" />)
        }
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   public void product(int value)
        {
         if( value > 60)
        }
```

**Remember**:

1. **When the output method is "text**", any characters that are escaped in the XML document, such as `&`, `<` (`>`, `&quot;` and `&apos;` usually do not need to be escaped at all) are produced unescaped in the output.
2. **Always try to avoid using DOE** -- it is almost never required.