# How do I 'mix and match' entity translation in XSLT2 replace() function?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm experimenting with XSLT2, using a stylesheet based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8903169/533832) answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="source/text()">
  <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '&lt;.*?&gt;', '<ph>$0</ph>')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which is intended to do multiple replacements, eg from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file>
    <source>abc &lt;field1&gt; def &lt;field2&gt; ghi</source>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file>
    <source>abc <ph>&lt;field1&gt;</ph> def <ph>&lt;field2&gt;</ph> ghi</source>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

However my transform is not valid, I get this error:

```
Error on line 12 column 54 of my.xsl:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The value of attribute "select" associated with an
  element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

If I use `select="replace(., '&lt;(.*?)&gt;', '&lt;ph&gt;F&lt;/phgt;')"` then I get `...&lt;ph&gt;...` in the output.

If I use [DOE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716998/xslt-escaping-gt) I introduce other problems because there might me other entities in the field I want to leave untouched. If I use `<xsl:output method="text"/>` I lose most of my xml - is there some other way of 'mixing and matching' like this?

Comment: This is possible, but not as a string replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is here**:

```
<xsl:sequence select="replace(., '&lt;(.*?)&gt;', '<ph>F</ph>')"/>
```

**A well-formed XML document cannot contain the `<` character in an attribute value**.

In this particular case, the `select` attribute above contains the substring `<ph>F</ph>` and this causes the stylesheet even not to be parsed as an XML document.

**And, more importantly, elements cannot be generated just by string replacement** -- the result will be just string (containing encoded element representation) -- not element.

**Here is how to achieve what you want**:

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="source/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;(.*?)&gt;">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <ph><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></ph>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
    <file>
        <source>abc &lt;field1&gt; def &lt;field2&gt; ghi</source>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
      <file>
            <source>abc <ph>field1</ph> def <ph>field2</ph> ghi</source>
      </file>
</xliff>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of the XSLT 2.0 instructions **[`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#analyze-string)**, **[`<xsl:matching-substring>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-matching-substring)**, **[`<xsl:non-matching-substring>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-non-matching-substring)** and **[`regex-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-regex-group)**

Comment: Don't you want to use `<ph><xsl:value-of select="."/></ph>` in your `xsl:matching-substring`?

Comment: I've adapted this for my real-world needs - which was easy thanks to your correct and very clear answer (though @DevNull is right I think - just some slight carry-over from a previous question :-)

Comment: @DevNull: Why? The OP himself uses `<ph>F</ph>` in his question.

Comment: @Jack Douglas: You are welcome. As for the `<ph>F</ph>` -- this is exactly what you are using in the question.

Comment: @Dimitre - I didn't notice that the OP used `<ph>F</ph>` in the XSLT; I was looking at the wanted XML output.

Comment: @DevNull: Wow,... so this is the reason for yours and mine confusion... :)

Comment: My apologies to you both - I've updated the question to remove the confusion.

Comment: @Jack Douglas and DevNull: I modified the answer accordingly. Note that it isn't just `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` but `<xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>`

Comment: "." fits the question but "regex-group(1)" is very handy to know about, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the string `&lt;` appears in your source document, then the XDM tree representation of the document will contain the character '<' in its place, which will match the regex '<', which is written in your stylesheet as `&lt;`.

So it should work, but you've obviously done something wrong. Show us what you did, and we might have a chance to tell you where you went wrong. Telling us you ran into problems is not much use if you don't tell us what the problems were.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael - I've updated the question to show exactly what I've tried. The 'search' bit with the regex works fine as you say it should - but I'm having trouble with the 'replace' side

Comment: The problem is that @Jack-Douglas wants to generate elements simply by string replacement -- this is not possible. Elements are nodes and must be created not as substrings of a string. The solution is to use `<xsl:analyze-string>` -- as in my answer.